# How to get a specific file from directory in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Using `Directory.GetFiles()` returns all the files in the directory as follows:

```
var sqlFiles = Directory.GetFiles($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Content\\DbScripts\\","*.sql");
```

Actually I need a specific file from that directory. What I have tried so far as follows but don't work!

```
var localizationSqlFile = Directory.GetFiles($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Content\\DbScripts\\Localizations.sql").FirstOrDefault();
```

It throws expection:

> The directory name is invalid.\r\n

Is there any method in C# to get a single file from a directory? If not then what will be most efficient way?

Comment: If you know the name of the file you want, you can just use `if (File.Exists(fullPathName)) ...`

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Content\\DbScripts").FirstOrDefault(d => d.Contains("Localizations.sql")` should also work.

Comment: Directory.GetFiles returns an array of Strings, if you already know the string (file name), why do you need GetFiles? Or maybe @MatthewWatson is right, you just want to check if it exists?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! I am trying the both method you proposed!

Comment: `string yourFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Content", "DbScripts", "Localizations.sql");`

Comment: If you only want to read the content of that file you could just use `var content = File.ReadAllText(fullPathToFile);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Please write your comment as answer so that I can accept it as  answer.

Comment: JohnSmith It's ok, user @gocki has given the answer!

Comment: @MatthewWatson But you commented rightly before his answer! Thanks for you generosity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get the bytes of a certain file and you already have the full path, you can use the static method File.ReadAllBytes

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(myPath);
```

If you want to get file infos, you can create a new FileInfo object

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(myPath);
```

If you just want to check, if a file exists, you can also use the method File.Exist

```
if (File.Exists(myPath))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file from your sqlFiles returned

```
var sqlFiles = Directory.GetFiles($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Content\\DbScripts\\","*.sql");
var yourFile = sqlFiles.FirstOrDefault(x=> Path.GetFileName(x) == "Localizations.sql");
```